# CSS nth Query With Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a setup similar to

```html
<div class="charts">Content</div>
<div class="tables">Content</div>
....
<div class="charts">Content</div>
<div class="tables">Content</div>
```

It repeats several times. My CSS is as follows

```css
.left {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
div.tables:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: both;
        background-color:red;
}
 div.charts:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: both;
        background-color:green;
}
```

Using jQuery, I initially hide all DIV elements with the `charts` class and using a click function, I then show all `charts` and hide all `tables` DIVs. The CSS

What happens however is then upon loading the page, the DIV elements named `charts` are still recognised meaning the first `tables` DIV is shown, then there's two blank slots where I want two more DIVs with a class of `tables` being shown.

Hopefully this jsfiddle makes sense http://jsfiddle.net/gyjJU/3/ and also http://jsfiddle.net/gyjJU/4/

Comment: `What happens however is then upon loading the page, the DIV elements named charts are still recognised meaning the first tables DIV is shown, then there's two blank slots where I want two more DIVs with a class of tables being shown.` this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I thought someone might say this. I would have left it at ".left:nth-child(3n+4)" but that didn't work. For the visible elements I want the clear to apply but I want the hidden elements to be ignored totally but it seems CSS is still picking them up

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me. What's the problem? What does the CSS have to do with this? Is the problem the charts/tables showing/not showing?

Comment: Don't you want to use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child` ?

Comment: The top right DIV is not showing the text "TABLES"

Comment: Just because an element is hidden (or not visible) doesn't mean it's not part of the DOM. `nth-child` selectors will still "see" these hidden elements. Why don't you just add additional classes to apply the styling for `3n+4`?

Comment: @mguimard `nth-of-type` works on tags, but apparently not on classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get the result you desire just by changing your CSS selectors to take into account the hidden alternating elements:

```
div.tables:nth-child(6n+8) {
    clear: both;
    background-color:red;
}
div.charts:nth-child(6n+7) {
    clear: both;
    background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gyjJU/5/